# Laravel: One to many and many to many relationship on one model

Tags: laravel

So let's assume we have two Models based on our tables (Post and Tag)

The Post has a (one to many) relationship to have a so called Highlighted Tag field which only accepts one tag.

The Post has also a (many to many) relationship to have tags assigned to that post, So it's just like normal tags.

As far as I understand, You can not have more than one relationship assigned to the same Table, How is this possible using Laravel? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want that a post has a main(highlighted tag) tag and multiple normal tags. This is pretty easy.

Your Post model functions:

```
public function tag()
{
    //Your highlighted tag
    return $this->belongsTo(Tag::class);
}

public function tags()
{
    //All normal tags
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::class);
}
```

And these are the columns of your tables:

`posts` table:

```
id: int
title: string
content: string
tag_id: int
```

`tags` table:

```
id: int
name: string
post_id: int
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, We need many to many relationship to have tags in the first place. One to many doesn't work.
Also in the answer we are short 1 database field, Where we put the highlighted tag id!?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do following : 

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{

    public function tags(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }

    public function highlightedtag(){

        return $this->tags->where('tag_type', 'highlighted')->first();
    }

}

?>

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{

    public function posts(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: To have tags you need to have a many to many relationship, one to many doesn't work at all, And in the answer, you are not accounting for other posts having the same highlighted tag.